# Read/Write in Windows Phone 8 C# application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need some help about the following program code! Why this code (write) throw an error?

Writing:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile f = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(f.OpenFile("data.cfg", FileMode.Create)))
    {
        w.Write(penz.Text + " || " + tipus.Text + " || " + DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute + ":" + DateTime.Now.Second);
    }
}
```

Reading:

```
IsolatedStorageFile f = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
{
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f.OpenFile("data.cfg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
    {
        fullmoney = int.Parse(r.ReadLine());
        teljes.Text = "Full Money: " + fullmoney + " .-";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: And are you only getting an error during writing?

Comment: I bet he is getting a file-exists exception because of FileMode.Create.

Comment: This is the error message: An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional information: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

Comment: Why don't you use `using` for reading? Do you get exception during writing after you performed read operation?